# Parametrize and loop KQL queries in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab, azure-data-explorer, kql

My question is how to assign variables within a loop in KQL magic command in Jupyter lab. I refer to Microsoft's document on this subject and will base my question on the code given here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kqlmagic

#### 1. First query below

```
%%kql  
StormEvents  
| summarize max(DamageProperty) by State  
| order by max_DamageProperty desc  
| limit 10
```

#### 2. Second: Convert the resultant query to a dataframe and assign a variable to 'statefilter'

```
df = _kql_raw_result_.to_dataframe()  
statefilter =df.loc[0].State  
statefilter
```

#### 3. This is where I would like to modify the above query and let statefilter have multiple variables (i.e. consist of different states):

```
df = _kql_raw_result_.to_dataframe()  
statefilter =df.loc[0:3].State  
statefilter
```

#### 4. And finally I would like to run my kql query within a for loop for each of the variables within statefilter. This below syntax may not be correct but it can give an example for what I am looking for:

```
dfs = [] # an empty list to store dataframes  

for state in statefilters:  
  %%kql  
  let _state = state;  
  StormEvents  
  | where State in (_state)  
  | do some operations here for that specific state   
  df = _kql_raw_result_.to_dataframe()  
  dfs.append(df)  # store the df specific to state in the list
```

The reason why I am not querying all the desired states within the KQL query is to prevent resulting in really large query outcomes being assigned to dataframes. This is not for this sample `StormEvents` table which has a reasonable size but for my research data which consists of many sites and is really big. Therefore I would like to be able to run a KQL query/analysis for each site within a for loop and assign each site's query results to a dataframe. Please let me know if this is possible or perhaps there may other logical ways to do this within KQL...

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways to do it.

The simplest is to refractor your %%kql cell magic to a %kql line magic.
Line magic can be embedded in python cell.

Other option is to: from Kqlmagic import kql
The Kqlmagic kql method, accept as a string a kql cell or line.
You can call kql from python.

Third way is to call the kql magic via the ipython method:
ip.run_cell_magic('kql', {your kql magic cell text})
You can call it from python.

Comment: thank you for your answer Micheal. Is there a reference document or any examples that I can refer to for your suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Example of using the single line magic mentioned by Michael and a return statement that converted the result to JSON. Without the conversion to JSON I wasn't getting anything back.

```
def testKQL():
    %kql DatabaseName | take 10000
    return _kql_raw_result_.to_dataframe().to_json(orient='records')
```